# dropping anything iptables with iptables and still can chat on IRC. why?

Tags: linux, iptables, irc

Here is the rule set :

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables-restore -v<<END
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Sep 22 17:45:30 2014
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [2:441]
-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j LOG
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j LOG
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 22 17:45:30 2014

END
```

gives :

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Sep 22 17:45:30 2014
Flushing chain `INPUT'
Flushing chain `FORWARD'
Flushing chain `OUTPUT'
# Completed on Mon Sep 22 17:45:30 2014
```

dropping anything iptables with iptables and still can chat on IRC. why ?
Any ideas ?

```
thorsten@thorstysPC ~ $ lsmod | grep ipt
iptable_filter         12810  1 
ip_tables              27239  1 iptable_filter
x_tables               34059  4 ip_tables,xt_tcpudp,xt_LOG,iptable_filter
thorsten@thorstysPC ~ $
```

This is the list of modules. Looks like IPtables is online.
Can anyone check these on his own box ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I misunderstood the question. That's why I deleted the original answer's text but will keep the answer unless the problem is solved because there is still an open discussion below. If it can't be solved, I'll delete this answer.

Comment: I want to block anything, but websites.

Comment: I do not understand, why IRC is NOT being blocked

Comment: Are you shure iptables is enabled at all?

Comment: might be a kernel bug ?!?

Comment: do you need the modules list

Comment: what gives you `iptables-restore -v <<END ...` ?